# Trimming my retzuos

Tags: tefilin

So, I recently recieved a pair of tefillin and have been laying them everyday since (about four weeks.) I've noticed that the retzuos on the shel yad are a bit too long for the length and width of my arm and hand, so I was wondering if I could simply cut off a little of the strap. I know you can trim it when you haven't used the tefillin for a mitzvoh yet, but I didn't know about trimming them after I've already worn them for four weeks. Mi yodeya? (BTW, they are Nusach Ari)

Comment: I think the only part that is left unanswered in the question you linked is whether the part you cut can be thrown or has to be put in geniza. Shulchan Aruch 154:3 says it it tashmishei kedusha and therefore has to be put in geniza

Comment: @MichaelBloch, AFAIK everyone holds like the Sh"A.